# Apks files download but will not install?

Tags: updates, installation, apk, downloading, downgrade

I wanted to downgrade my YouTube app so I got a few APK files from previous versions, and they downloaded successfully . When I clicked on them to install, the page showing install and cancel came up. Once I chose the install button it took me a page which said installing, but it immediately stopped and told me the app is not installed (picture) . I tried this with 3 different apk files and through many downgrading apps but i emded up in the same place and the same thing kept on happening. Background info: Samsung s4 mini, 700mb storage space, unknown sourced apps allowed. Someone please help I hate this update.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded the **YouTube** app, then you can easily downgrade it. Just open **YouTube**'s app info and then click **Uninstall Updates** button. In this way you can get the default version of **YouTube** back.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. uninstall all YouTube updates: Manage Apps >> YouTube >>> Uninstall
   Updates/Disable,
2. Disable all automatic updates. Go the Google
   Play store >>> Settings >>> Auto Update Apps >>> then select " DO
   not auto update apps".
3. Then try installing the apks you have.

Other things to check:

- Check your android version. Do do so go to settings >> About Phone >>
  Android version. For an S4 mini it will either be 4.2.2 (Jellybean)
  or 4.4.2 (KitKat).
- Make sure the apk you downloaded was for the same version of android
  that was on your phone.